# Voiceover detection in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ipad, accessibility, voiceover

Working on accessibility for a web application for ipad users.
I want to know when the user performs the default action for the item in the VoiceOver cursor by using VO + space bar.

How can I detect that event?

Comment: You won't be able to target VO + any key (including spacebar) because VoiceOver consumes the VO keydowns (by default control+option).  You should probably just make stuff work the same regardless of whether assistive technology is being used or not.

Comment: @harris I have some popover that I want to disable it if the user is using ipad when the VO is on.

Comment: Unfortunately there won't be anyway to detect due to the keydown consumption of AT that I described above.  Why do you want to disable it specifically for VO iOS users?

Comment: You can try adding a keydown listener and check if `e.ctrlKey` is `true`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to detect if VoiceOver is on in a web page on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747942/is-it-possible-to-detect-if-voiceover-is-on-in-a-web-page-on-iphone)